# How to update a Python Dataframe column dependent on the presence of a substring in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe containing a float64 type column and an object type column containing a string.

If object column contains substring 'abc' I want to subtract 12 from the float column. If object column contains substring 'def' I want to subtract 24 from the float column. If object column contains neither 'abc' or 'def', I want to leave float column as is.

Example:

```
Nmbr      Strng
 52       abcghi
 80       defghi
 10       ghijkl
```

Expected output:

```
Nmbr      Strng
 40       abcghi
 56       defghi
 10       ghijkl
```

I have tried the following but keep getting an error:

```
if df.Strng.str.contains("abc"):
    df.Nmbr = (df.Nmbr - 12)
elif df.Strng.str.contains("def"):
    df.Nmbr = (df.Nmbr - 24)
else:
    df.Nmbr = df.Nmbr
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
915         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
916                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
917                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
918 
919     __bool__ = __nonzero__
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Note:Line 917 is the one that's highlighted as the error.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: Please include the errors in your post.

Comment: Apologies - the original post has been edited to include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs because you are testing whether a Boolean series is `True` or `False`. This is not possible. You *could* test if all or any values are `True`, to return a single Boolean, but this isn't what you are looking for.

It is good practice to vectorize your calculations rather than introduce loops. Below is how you can implement your logic via the `.loc` accessor.

```
df.loc[df['Strng'].str.contains('abc', regex=False, na=False), 'Nmbr'] -= 12
df.loc[df['Strng'].str.contains('def', regex=False, na=False), 'Nmbr'] -= 24
```

Result:

```
   Nmbr   Strng
0    40  abcghi
1    56  defghi
2    10  ghijkl
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative code suggestion - this has worked for me. Also, appreciate you explaining why my original code hadn't worked. So am I correct in that there is no way I could use an if statement to do what I was trying to do?

Comment: @Linda, that's correct. If this answer helped, feel free to accept (green tick on left), so other users know.